# Running my script whenever other program is started

Tags: linux

I want to run my script whenever some other program starts running(ex. Document Viewer). How can I do this?

Comment: Which distro / desktop environment?

Answer (score 1):

With a wrapper script.

1. Move or rename the tool so it's not reachable by standard `$PATH` with its usual name.
2. Create a wrapper script that launches your script (in the background if needed) then `exec`-s to the real tool (or the other way around: launches the real tool in the background and `exec`-s to your script; but this may backfire if another program calls the wrapper and sticks to its PID thinking it's the tool).
3. Place the wrapper script where the tool was, adjust permissions etc. Let it impersonate the real tool.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

/path/to/your/script &
exec /new/path/to/the/real/tool ${1+"$@"}
```

Notes:

- `${1+"$@"}` hack is explained [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WrapperScript). You would probably be fine with usual `"$@"`.
- Your script will be run by whoever runs the wrapper. It may or may not be what you want.
- In the above example your script is a child of the wrapper, which is then replaced by the tool. Your script can find out its parent's PID, wait until `readlink /proc/<ppid>/exe` returns the real tool location, then interact with the tool using signals or whatever.